# Unable to retrieve Req.Query on Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently trying to retrieve my Query String data to use it as a parameter for my OpenWeather API call later on.

I am having issues retrieving the Query String that is being sent to my server although it appears on the URL request. I keep getting "undefined" when I try to console.log the req.query on my server. I'm guessing that I didn't parse the Query String data properly which causes it to be "undefined". So looking at the picture i've attached, using the city=Tokyo as my req.query.

I've pasted the client-side, server-side, and screenshots of my web app.

Any ideas?

P.S. I've just started learning, so I'm sorry in advance

```
**Client-Side JS file**


let cityForm = document.querySelector('#cityName');
let city = document.querySelector('#city');
let button = document.querySelector('#btn');

button.addEventListener('click', getData);

async function getData () {
  
  console.log('Value entered '+ city.value);

  let options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/text'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(city.value)
  };

  
  console.log('value being sent ' + options.body);

  let fetchin = await fetch('/', options); // making the post request here to the server

  let rezponse = await fetchin.json();
  console.log(rezponse);

};
```

```
**Server-Side JS file**

let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let fetch = require('node-fetch');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('view engine','ejs');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  res.render('home');
});

app.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
  console.log('The value of the query '+ req.query);
  
// let user = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + req.query.city + '&appid=APIKEY');

  // let item = await user.json();

  // res.json(user);
  // console.log(item);

//Idea is to use the req.query coming from the client-side to use for 
in the API call to OpenWeather, get the details from the API and send it back

});

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
  console.log('Post has been called');
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `search params` that are required to be added to the url, so that you can access them on the server

```
  //client side
  let options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/text'
    }
  };
  let url = new URL('/');
  url.searchParams.set('q', 'Tokyo')
  let fetchin = await fetch(url, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side, you are trying to log the `req.query` when you `post` to `/`.

```
app.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
  console.log('The value of the query '+ req.query);
```

However, on the client-side, you are posting to `/` without any query params.

```
let fetchin = await fetch('/', options);
```

You could append the query params to `/` like shown below.

```
let fetchin = await fetch(`/city=${city.value}`, options);
```

OR

Since you are already posting the `city.value` as the post body from the client side, on the server side you can access it using `req.body`.

```
app.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
  console.log('The value of req body '+ req.body);
```

Comment: hey man, thanks for the suggestion. I am aware I could just pull the req.body since I am passing the data over. But I wanted to experiment and try to pull the query string.

Comment: tried to append the query params as you suggested, but it still doesn't work. I get a POST message error